# contains and equal condition faling on equal strings, encryption and decryption

Tags: if-statement, encryption, conditional-statements, equals, contains

dear stackoverflow helpers
I was just testing my skills and learning the same way as i always do when i encountered something strange, searched the web but just couldn'
t find out what was going wrong.

I was trying to build an encryption program storing its keys in a isostream.
The first time you can write the key without a condition, however after that you need to put in the old key

```
        (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("key.txt", FileMode.CreateNew, isoStore))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(isoStream))
                {
                    //keycreation begin
                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    int random1 = rnd.Next(20000, 2000000); //number between 2000 and 2 million
                    stringrandom0 = random1.ToString();
                    char[] chars = "$%#@!*abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890?;:ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ^&".ToCharArray();
                    Random r = new Random();
                    int i = r.Next(chars.Length);
                    int q = r.Next(chars.Length);
                    int w = r.Next(chars.Length);
                    stringrandom1 = chars[i].ToString();
                    stringrandom2 = chars[q].ToString();
                    stringrandom3 = chars[w].ToString();
                    int random2 = rnd.Next(20000, 2000000); //number between 2000 and 2 million
                    stringrandom4 = random2.ToString();
                    key = stringrandom0 + stringrandom1 + stringrandom2 + stringrandom3 + stringrandom4;
                    textBox2.Text = "Creation & Encryption succesful finished your key = " + key + " do not lose this key!";
                    //key will look like this: letters, numbers, letters
                    //key creation end

                    writer.WriteLine(key);

                    File.Create(@"C:\Users\Legion\Desktop\encryption\text\" + fileName1).Close();
                    //Console.WriteLine("You have written to the file.");
                }
            }
```

So it gave me a key: when things didn't work out i let it display in a textbox to be sure. I recieve it this way.

```
      IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null);
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("key.txt", FileMode.Open, isoStore))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(isoStream))
            {
                keyentered = textBox4.Text;
                checkkey = (reader.ReadToEnd());
                textBox1.Text = checkkey;
                textBox3.Text = keyentered;
            }
        }
```

as you can see the code i enter is set to keyenter, i entered this: 156216*ek316677.

Checkkey reads the written piece, and ofcourse to check, i put it to a textbox to and it displayed this: (exactly without spaces) 156216*ek316677.

Comparison
156216*ek316677.
156216*ek316677.

So this is the check code

```
if (isoStore.FileExists("key.txt"))
        {
             using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("key.txt", FileMode.Open, isoStore))
            {
                if (keyentered.Contains(checkkey) || checkkey == keyentered)
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(isoStream))
                    {
                        //keycreation begin
                        Random rnd = new Random();
                        int random1 = rnd.Next(20000, 2000000); //number between 2000 and 2 million
                        stringrandom0 = random1.ToString();
                        char[] chars = "$%#@!*abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890?;:ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ^&".ToCharArray();
                        Random r = new Random();
                        int i = r.Next(chars.Length);
                        int q = r.Next(chars.Length);
                        int w = r.Next(chars.Length);
                        stringrandom1 = chars[i].ToString();
                        stringrandom2 = chars[q].ToString();
                        stringrandom3 = chars[w].ToString();
                        int random2 = rnd.Next(20000, 2000000); //number between 2000 and 2 million
                        stringrandom4 = random2.ToString();
                        key = stringrandom0 + stringrandom1 + stringrandom2 + stringrandom3 + stringrandom4;
                        textBox2.Text = "Creation & Encryption succesful finished your key = " + key + " do not lose this key!";
                        //key will look like this: letters, numbers, letters
                        //key creation end

                        writer.WriteLine(key);

                        File.Create(@"C:\Users\Legion\Desktop\encryption\text\" + fileName1).Close();
                        //Console.WriteLine("You have written to the file.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    textBox2.Text = "invalid key entered!";
                }
            }
        }
```

the problem is that it keeps saying invalid key entered, while they are exactly equal, so why does the if condition fails?
I tried a contains to but it fails exactly the same way.

Thanks for any help i might get.
Cheers godarcher, hobyist and nerd. :D

Comment: What values do you have in variables used in expression `keyentered.Contains(checkkey) || checkkey == keyentered` which can be contracted to `keyentered.Contains(checkkey)` (I think)?

Comment: The declaration of the values? Just public static string keyentered = "";

Comment: No, when using the debugger, what are the values of `keyentered` and `checkkey` when it reaches `if (keyentered.Contains(checkkey) || checkkey == keyentered)`?

Comment: i debugged it with a breakpoint. checkkey = 156216*ek316677\r\n and keyentered is empty! EDIT: i fixed it this way the declaration was at a place that made it not work, thx a lot